# Como faço para não repetir string de vetores repetidos

Tags: c, array, struct, for, vector

Preciso fazer uma consulta em uma struct e comparar todos os *.location* para imprimir somente 1 vez sem repetição, cada um deles com seus respectivos valores armazenados.

```
struct archive{
    char    Title[N];
    char    autorName[N]; 
    char    pCompany[N];
    char    location[N];
    int     amount;
    int     releaseDate; 
    int     edition; 
    int     isbn;
};
```

As minhas tentativas de realizar essa ação falharam, eis um exemplo:

```
            // listar cada local separadamente
                for(int i=0; i < quant+countBook; i++){
                    if(strcmp(book[i].location, book[i].location) == 0){
                        printf("%s\n", book[i].location);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Se apesar de poderem existir repetições você quer imprimir apenas um então para ao encontrar o primeiro. Agora isto `(strcmp(book[i].location, book[i].location) == 0)` sempre dará verdadeiro já que não imagino como algo possa ser diferente dele mesmo.

Comment: Concordo, porém foi a primeira coisa que veio na mente, embora eu tenha tentado utilizar outro laço *for* então alterando o segundo argumento do strcmp() para j e da mesma maneira não funcionou. E o objetivo dessa função é: listar os vetores da struct de forma ordenada pelo *location*, e não deveria imprimir 2 vezes ou mais o mesmo *location* já que na primeira impressão já mostraria todos os dados relacionados a ele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de imprimir verifique se é uma duplicata.

```
for(int i=0; i < quant+countBook; i++){
    int ja=0;
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        if(strcmp(book[i].location, book[j].location) == 0){
            ja++;
        }
    }
    if (ja == 0){
        printf("%s\n", book[i].location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu preciso, muito obrigado!